# Why would Pytorch (CUDA) be running slow on GPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have been playing around with Pytorch on Linux for some time now and recently decided to try get more scripts to run with my GPU on my Windows desktop. Since trying this I have noticed a massive performance difference between my GPU execution time and my CPU execution time, on the same scripts, such that my GPU is significantly slow than CPU. To illustrate this I just a tutorial program found here (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html#pytorch-tensors)

```
import torch
import datetime
print(torch.__version__)

dtype = torch.double
#device = torch.device("cpu")
device = torch.device("cuda:0")

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

# Create random input and output data
x = torch.randn(N, D_in, device=device, dtype=dtype)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = torch.randn(D_in, H, device=device, dtype=dtype)
w2 = torch.randn(H, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)


start = datetime.datetime.now()
learning_rate = 1e-6
for t in range(5000):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y
    h = x.mm(w1)
    h_relu = h.clamp(min=0)
    y_pred = h_relu.mm(w2)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = (y_pred - y).pow(2).sum().item()
    #print(t, loss)

    # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
    grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
    grad_w2 = h_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred)
    grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.mm(w2.t())
    grad_h = grad_h_relu.clone()
    grad_h[h < 0] = 0
    grad_w1 = x.t().mm(grad_h)

    # Update weights using gradient descent
    w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
    w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2

end = datetime.datetime.now()

print(end-start)
```

I increased the number of Epoch's from 500 to 5000 as I have read that the first CUDA call is very slow due to initialisation. However the performance issue still exists.

With `device = torch.device("cpu")` the final time printed out is normal around 3-4 seconds, well `device = torch.device("cuda:0")` executes in around 13-15 seconds

I have reinstalled Pytorch a number of different ways (uninstalling the previous installation of course) and the problem still persists. I am hoping that someone can help me, if I have perhaps missed a set (didn't install some other API/program) or am doing something wrong in the code.

Python: v3.6

Pytorch:v0.4.1

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

Any help would be appreciated :slight_smile:

Comment: Disclaimer: I have also asked this question on the pytorch forums (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-is-pytorch-cuda-running-slow-on-gpu/25737), just don't know how active they are.

Comment: what is your CUDA version? How many GPU do you have ?

Comment: According to Pytorch, Cuda version is 9.0 (Got using `torch.version.cuda`). And I only have 1 1060

Comment: Can you try with this code ? change line 85-87 to see cuda and cpu speed. https://gist.github.com/salihkaragoz/88d313df6a7c91e64a7c3be0df003e6e

Comment: if you post the speed results of cuda and cpu with above code, I can help. Most probably the problem related to small computation.

Comment: So with your example, CUDA runs in roughly 5 seconds, and CPU runs in around 15 seconds (per epoch). I notice that your NN is a fair bit larger than mine. Also you are using the Net template to build you NN. Is it just based off the size of the network or does the example I posted have something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running on gpu could be expensive when you run with smaller batch size. If you put more data to gpu, means increasing the batch size, then you could observe significance amount of increase in data. Yes gpu is running better with float32 than double. 
Try this

**

```
N, D_in, H, D_out = 128, 1000, 500, 10
dtype = torch.float32
```

**

Answer (score 2):

Main reason is you are using double data type instead of float. GPUs are mostly optimized for operations on 32-bit floating numbers. If you change your dtype to torch.float your GPU run should be faster than your CPU run even including stuff like CUDA initialization.

Comment: This did drastically improve the performance of the network, though it did not make cuda faster than my cpu. What did in fact improve make cuda fasterwas increasing the size of the network drastically. I added two more larger layers and that needed up improving cuda's performance against the cpu.